# What is a 'potential convert' called in hebrew/yiddish?

Tags: hebrew, conversion-to-judaism, pronunciation, yiddish

I know that a convert is called a ger tzedek. While a righteous non-Jew/goy is called a goy tzedek. From what I have found so far online, most just say/use "potential convert" when referring to someone who is on the path to conversion.

I did not think Ba'al Teshuva was appropriate but I can see it being argued.

Comment: Why do you think Baal yeshiva cannot describe a goy? Is there a reason to think even if he wasn't exploring gerus he still couldn't be a Baal teshuvah as a ben noach?

Comment: Maybe בא להתגייר?

Comment: משוגענע גוי my grandma would call him

Comment: Is this on-topic?